# How do I convert integer to an n-tuple, given that I know how the integer was computed?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have an integer `n`, and a 6-tuple: `(a,b,c,d,e,f)`. Each element of the tuple has a range:

```
a : 0 to 4
b : 0 to 4
c : 0 to 3
d : 0 to 4
e : 0 to 2
f : 0 to 4
```

`n` can be computed as follows: `n = 5a + 5b + 4c + 5d + 3e + 5f`. The coefficients on the tuple elements are just the size their respective ranges.

We assign a mapping from `\mathbb{Z}` to `\mathbb{Z}^6` as follows:

```
0 -> (0,0,0,0,0,0)
1 -> (0,0,0,0,0,1)
...
6 -> (0,0,0,0,1,0)
7 -> (0,0,0,0,1,1)
```

Is there a decently efficient way to take that integer `n` and find the corresponding tuple `(a,b,c,d,e,f)`?

Comment: There is no "the" corresponding tuple. There is "a" corresponding tuple. There are four different tuples with $n=5$, for example.

Comment: if we decide to permute first through `f`, then `e`, then `d`, for example, does that allow uniqueness?

Comment: That means you are putting additional restrictions on your parameters. And I hardly think so. See that $4 + 2\cdot 3 = 2\cdot 5 = 5 + 5$ are three patterns all summing to $10$ and being valid in your question. You probably want to generalize a $b$-adic representation of a number ($n = \sum_{i=0}^N a_i b^i$). In this case your multipliers must be chosen differently.

Comment: So how would I do that? One additional restriction is that successive n must be separated by 1.

Comment: I don't understand your additional restriction... You could simply multiply everything by $2$ in the end if you want $n$ to only take the values $2,4,\ldots$ or what do you mean?

Comment: I want n to take only values `0,1,2,...`.

Comment: Then my answer is correct as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the map
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i x_i$$
a bijection ($f(x)=n$ and $x = (a,b,c,d,e,f)$ in your OP) where $x_i$ can take the values $0$ to $M_i-1$ can be consructed by chosing $a_1 = 1$ and
$$a_{i+1} = a_i M_i$$
Here you'd get
$$f(a,b,c,d,e,f) = a + 5b + 25c + 100d + 400e + 1200f$$
The inverse is given by
$$(f^{-1}(n))_i = (n \mathop{\rm div} a_i) \bmod M_i$$
Where $\mathop{\rm div}$ is integer division and $\bmod$ is remainder (i.e. $n = n \mathop{\rm div} N + n \bmod N$ for all $n,N$)

Comment: In your formula, is $a$ the vector of ranges? Analogous to my (5,5,4,5,3,5)? Also, is the 0 index the furthest left or the furthest right?

Comment: My indices start with $1$. It doesn't matter if your read left-to-right or right-to-left, but I use left-to-right Notation. $a$ is a vector of some constants computed from the vector $M$, the vector of ranges. You can read the specific $a$ from the formula for $f$ wich I gave.